# Do footwraps need tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis, shoes

Do [footwraps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footwraps) (rectangular cloths wrapped around the feet in lieu of socks) need tzitzis?

I see two problems:

1. tzitzis could defeat the purpose of footwraps, making them much less comfortable.
2. putting tzitzis on feet could be considered disrespectful to the mitzvah.

A possible "solution" to both problems would be to arrange for tzitzis to hang out of boots (but that is a dubious solution at best).

Size cannot exempt footwraps because they are usually at least as large as the talit qatan worn by kids.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79360/759

Comment: @DoubleAA: thanks! So the answer is two-fold: (a) not necessary because it's feet, not body (b) make round corners just in case.

Comment: Are footwraps considered a "beged" - a "garment"? Seems that one doesn't normally "wear" a footwrap.

Comment: @DanF: if one "wears" shoes, socks, and underwear, I see no reason why footwraps would be different.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81571/what-is-considered-a-four-cornered-garment/81572#81572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various reasons as to why these may not need Tzitzis. I am here to quote one interesting one in particular, but I will note some of the possible other Heterim and sources:

- Potentially size too small (I realize that you excluded this, but it may still be the case with some footwraps): ([Tzitzis on a Scarf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79360/tzitzis-on-a-scarf))
- Not a garment for the body (there)
- Corners not made with two in the front/two in the back ([What is considered a four-cornered garment?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81571/what-is-considered-a-four-cornered-garment/81572#81572))

The Beis Yosef OC 10 (last paragraph) gives a very interesting reason that would apply to this case, namely, for Tzitzis that could be stepped on a lot, there is no Chiyuv, as they would consistently be breaking, and "Deracheha Darchei Noam", so they are Patur:

> אי נמי כיון שאם היינו מחייבים אותם בציצית היו נפסקין בכל עת הציציות התחתונים בדריסת הרגלים והיה צריך בכל עת לתקנם איכא למימר דלא חייבה תורה בכך דכל דרכיה דרכי נועם

(As an aside, the Beis Yosef makes no mention of disrespect to the Mitzvah here.)

To be Machmir above and beyond these Shitos, simply use a triangular one, or round the corner(s).