# Suit Jackets and Tzitzis

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, shiurim-measurements

I recently purchased a suit, and with Hashem's help it will be ready sometime this week. When I was at the suiting shop, I began thinking about whether or not my new suit would be obligated in tzitzis or not.

Normal suit jackets are single breasted, meaning there is one row of buttons. the corners there are almost always rounded, so there is no concern of the front two "corners" and the vents on the back of the jacket forming four corners and the garment being obligated in tzitzis. ([Picture](http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2016/E00%200241602%20017%2055%201493.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&set=key[hmver],value[4]&set=key[quality],value[80]&set=key[size],value[346x405]&call=url[file:/mobile/v2/product]))

My jacket, however, is double breasted, and so there really are four corners, when you count the front two and the vents. ([Picture](http://media.topman.com/wcsstore/TopMan/images/catalog/TM87J49MBLE_Zoom_F_1.jpg))

I was wondering whether my new jacket would be obligated in tzitzis. After all, there are four corners, but then again the vents do not go up the majority of the jacket and so there could actually be no concern at all.

Additionally, what about the lapels? Do they count as corners? Also, how long must the slit be in the jacket to make it obligated in tzitzis?

Comment: Some suits have one vent in the middle of the back and some have two vents more towards the sides.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Mine will have the latter. I suppose that gives it six corners. So would that change anything?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81571/759

Comment: @DoubleAA - OK, I just reached a mi.yodeya milestone... I literally do not remember asking that one. :)

Comment: you may also be interested in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11769/759

Comment: Do the vents go rov the way up ? If not, then it shouldn't be chayav AFAIK

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I wouldn't say so, but describe what it means to be most of the way up.